# Existence of Inverse of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A_{m\times n}$ be an $m\times n$ matrix (over a field $k$). Suppose there exist matrices $B_{n\times m}$ and $C_{n\times m}$ such that $AB=I_{m}$ and $CA=I_{n}$. We should expect *first* that $m=n$ and then $B=C$. This can be proved by considering the matrices as linear transformations on appropriate vector spaces, and using rank-nullity theorem.

But, while studying a book named "Matrices", I raised

**Question:** Can we prove $m=n$ by considering "only matrices" and not linear transformations and vector spaces?

---

(This question may have been appeared in stackexchange, but I didn't find this question. )

Comment: $B = (CA)B = C(AB) = C$ is easy.

Comment: yes! This we can see also in groups/rings etc.

Comment: So, do you need to prove that $B=C$ or $m=n$?

Comment: $m=n$ without considering vector spaces and linear transformations.

Comment: I also couldn't see in some standard books such as Lang, Bourbaki, Curties etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $m < n$.  So we pad out the matrices $A$ and $B$ so that they are $n\times n$ matrices:
$$ U = \begin{bmatrix} A\\0 \end{bmatrix}, \qquad V = \begin{bmatrix} B & 0 \end{bmatrix} .$$
Now
$$ VU = I_n, \text{ and }UV = \begin{bmatrix} I_m & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} .$$
Then $\det(VU) = 1$, and $\det(UV) = 0$.  But $\det(UV) = \det(U)\det(V) = \det(VU)$, and so we obtain a contradiction.

A similar argument should work in the case $m>n$.

Also, if determinants seem too complicated, if the characteristic of the field is zero, you can use trace instead: $\text{trace}(UV) = \text{trace}(VU)$ is easy to establish.

Comment: If we pad with zeros, then how can you write $U^{-1}$. Clearly $VU=I_n$ is not possible if $m<n$.

Comment: I quoted a theorem from the theory of $n \times n$ matrices, that if a matrix has a one sided inverse, then it is a two sided inverse.  However, I just added an alternative argument that uses determinants, in case you don't want to invoke that theorem.

Comment: @user44197 I changed the argument, using determinants instead.

Answer (score 3):

This can be generalized: If $A$ has both left and right inverse, then the two inverses have to be equal (and hence the same dimension etc.)

Proof: See Stephen's comment, but here it is again (Please give him the credit)

$$
CAB = (C A) B = B = C (AB) = C \Rightarrow B=C$$

You only associative properties and the property of $I$.